# help on Change Tracking in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database of 40 tables. I want to track the changes and keep record of every change made in database. what would be best option ?

Note: i am using MS SQL Server 2005.

i have tried following code for Change Tracking

ALTER DATABASE Customer
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(AUTO_CLEANUP = ON , CHANGE_RETENTION = 5 DAYS)

but gives error

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

if anyone could help me on this issue, i would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

You might give C2 auditing a try:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187634%28SQL.90%29.aspx

I believe you are trying to use a 2008 feature.